# Impala - Replace all data in a table's partition

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh, impala

I have a program that generates all the data concerning a Impala table partition. This program writes the data in a HDFS Text file.

How to (physically) remove all the data previously belonging to the partition and replace them with the data in the new Text file converted in Parquet format ?

If I physically remove the old Parquet files composing the partition using raw HDFS API, is it going to disturb Impala ?

Comment: Is your impala table an external table ?

Comment: It could be external or internal. I have the choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create table for your text files:

```
create external table stg_table (...) location '<your text file in hdfs>';
```

After external data change you have to refresh it:

```
refresh stg_table;
```

Then insert into you target table

```
insert overwrite table target_table select * from stg_table;
```

If your target table is partitioned, do this:

```
insert overwrite table target_table partiton(<partition spec>) select * from stg_table;
```

keyword 'overwrite' does the trick, it overwrites table or partition.

Comment: Thank you. It works. However the "insert overwrite" statement takes time. Moreover, I am not sure the operation is atomic. What's happen if Impala SQL queries concerning this partition arrive during the "insert overwrite" is running ? Is there a way to make this "partition exchange" process atomic and faster. Whats' about a ALTER statement to specify the location of the Parquet files for the partition ?

Comment: such as : "alter table p1 partition (month=1, day=1) set location '/usr/external_data/new_years_day';"

Comment: Or by programatically (with Hadoop FileSystem) delete the HDFS folder where Impala stores the partition, then re-create the folder with the Parquet files generated by my Spark job and finally do : "alter table t1 recover partitions"